# Proof for $(U+W)^\perp=U^\perp \cap W^\perp$ if $U$ and $W$ are subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Proof for $(U+W)^\perp=U^\perp \cap W^\perp$ if $U$ and $W$ are both subspaces.
Proof for $(U+W)^\perp=U^\perp \cap W^\perp$ if $U$ and $W$ are both subspaces.

Confused where to start
My Attempt
Let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$ over a field $K$.  In general, for a subset $S$ of $V$,
$$S^\perp:=\big\{f\in V^*\,\big|\,f(s)=0\text{ for every }s\in S\big\}$$ is a vector subspace of the algebraic dual $V^*=\text{Hom}_K(V,K)$ of $V$ (and $S^\perp$ does not sit within $V$, at least not canonically).  Then,
$$(U+W)^\perp = \big\{f\in V^*\,\big|\,f(u+w)=0\text{ for all }u\in U\text{ and }w\in W\big\}\,.$$
If $f\in (U+W)^\perp$, then $f(u)=f(u+0)=0$ and $f(w)=f(0+w)=0$ for all $u\in U$ and $w\in W$.  This shows that $f\in U^\perp \cap W^\perp$.

On the other hand, if $f\in U^\perp \cap W^\perp$, then by linearity, $f(u+w)=f(u)+(w)=0+0=0$ for all $u\in U$ and $w\in W$.  Thus, $f\in (U+W)^\perp$.  This shows that $(U+W)^\perp = U^\perp \cap W^\perp$.

However, if $V$ is endowed with a nondegenerate bilinear form $\langle\_,\_\rangle: V\times V\to K$ (this seems to be the case for the OP's question), then we can also define
$$S_\perp:=\big\{v\in V\,\big|\,\langle v,s\rangle =0\text{ for every }s\in S\big\}\,.$$
Using a similar argument as above, we have
$$(U+W)_\perp = U_\perp \cap W_\perp\,.$$

**P.S.**  We also have $(U\cap W)^\perp = U^\perp +W^\perp$ and, if $V$ is endowed with a nondegenerate bilinear form, $(U\cap W)_\perp = U_\perp +W_\perp$.  This is the part where the Axiom of Choice is needed.

Comment: By, $^\perp$, you do mean the orthogonal complement, don't you?

Comment: @GauravChandan,yes,no worries I have solved it